# how to find cpu usage by java process

Tags: java, jvm, cpu-usage

I want to moniter cpu usage of some java application. I don't want to use tools like
jconsole (JMX)

if there is any way to check by java code?

Comment: The way to do this is to use JMX.  You can call JMX from Java code, like any other Java code.

Comment: Or you can do this externally using `ps` or reading `/proc/{pid}` if you have Linux.

Comment: i want cpu usage in percentage by java process. how can i get using JMX?

Answer (score 1):

Use [JavaSysMon](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon/wiki)

Currently it reports:

- Process table (also available as a tree), including pid, ppid, name,
  command line, user, process size, resident process size, user time,
  and kernel time.
- Uptime
- Current process’s pid
- Total and free RAM
- Total and free swap
- CPU usage
- CPU frequency
- Number of CPUs

Also you can use jmx mbeans or get PID using Runtime.exec() and using that call platform-specific command like ps.

Comment: can you please check how to use getCPUUsage i am using CpuTimes.getCPUUsage but it always returns 1.0

Comment: CpuTimes ct = monitor.cpuTimes();
  ct.getCpuUsage(ct);

Comment: @Saurav you have source code try to debug , we can not tell anything seeing one line. you can start a new question for this problem and provide your code over there I am sure you will get answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

and run `top | grep java` command.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the MX Bean `ThreadMXBean` from the Java class itself and use the methods `get*CpuTime()`.

Otherwise, you can use good old `top` and grep on your Java process PID.

If you are brave enough, there is also `perf` tool in `linux-tools` package.

Hope that helps !